# css - highlight td elements after finding row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to highlight some td elements after find the row.
I managed to find the row and td elements in two different steps (commented 'Works OK'). I would like to combine the two steps in a inside a for loop but It is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = ['2017-11-02', '2017-11-03'];
  cell = $('td:contains("value1")');

  // works OK
  $(cell).css({
    color: "red",
    border: "2px solid red"
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < dt.length; i++) {
    // works OK
    $('[data-date="' + dt[i] + '"]').css({
      background: "blue",
      color: "white"
    });

    // Not Working
    //$('td:contains("value1")').find('[data-date="' + dt[i] + '"]').css({background:"blue", color:"white"});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>value1</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-01">1</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-02">2</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-03">3</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-04">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>value2</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-01">1</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-02">2</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-03">3</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-04">4</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: try [`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead of `find`

Comment: Does the `.find` not check children only?

Comment: $('td:contains("value1")').siblings('[data-date="' + dt[i] + '"]').css({background:"blue", color:"white"}); ?

Comment: oh yeah siblings should also work, maybe cleaner than parent.children :)

Comment: Thanks, with siblings is simlper and works just fine

Answer (score 0):

you can replace

```
$('[data-date="' + dt[i] + '"]').css({
```

with

```
$(cell).parent().children('[data-date="' + dt[i] + '"]').css({
```

you can replace children with find, and replace $(cell).parent() by a different way to focus on the tr.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = ['2017-11-02', '2017-11-03'];
  cell = $('td:contains("value1")');

  // works OK
  $(cell).css({
    color: "red",
    border: "2px solid red"
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < dt.length; i++) {
    // works OK
    $(cell).parent().children('[data-date="' + dt[i] + '"]').css({
      background: "blue",
      color: "white"
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>text1</td>
      <td>value1</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-01">1</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-02">2</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-03">3</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-04">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text2</td>
      <td>value2</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-01">1</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-02">2</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-03">3</td>
      <td data-date="2017-11-04">4</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```